# How to show the user that the name is not available in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

The user is going to make a character and give a name on the caracter. I have fixed so it will not insert data if the name exists but now I want to know how to show the user that the name is not available. The code will return 1 because it's not failing. The following is my code:

```
public int InsertAddventurer(Character Ad, int ClassId, out string errormsg)
{
    SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection();

    dbConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Adventurer;Integrated Security=True";

    String sqlstring = "" +
        "BEGIN " +
        "DECLARE @Id int; " +
        "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Ad_Fornamn FROM [Tbl_Adventurer] WHERE Ad_Fornamn = @name) " +
        "BEGIN " +
        "INSERT INTO[Tbl_Adventurer] " +
        "(Ad_Fornamn, Ad_Efternamn, Ad_Age, Ad_Rank) " +
        "Values(@Ad_Fornamn, @Ad_Efternamn, @Ad_Age, @Ad_Rank) " +
        "SELECT @Id = IDENT_CURRENT('Tbl_Adventurer'); " +
        "INSERT INTO[Tbl_Stats] " +
        "(Stats_Id, Strength, Dexterity, Constitution, Intelligence, Wisdom, Charisma) " +
        "Values(@Id, @Strength, @Dexterity, @Constitution, @Intelligence, @Wisdom, @Charisma) " +
        "INSERT INTO[Tbl_AdventurerKlass] " +
        "(Ad_Id, Kl_Id) " +
        "Values(@Id, @ClassId) " +
        "END " +
        "END";
    SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, dbConnection);

    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = Ad.Name;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("Ad_Fornamn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = Ad.Name;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("Ad_Efternamn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = Ad.Lastname;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("Ad_Age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Ad.Age;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("Ad_Rank", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Ad.Rank;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("Strength", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Ad.Strength;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("Dexterity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Ad.Dexterity;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("Constitution", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Ad.Constitution;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("Intelligence", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Ad.Intelligence;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("Wisdom", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Ad.Wisdom;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("Charisma", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Ad.Charisma;
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("ClassId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ClassId;

    try
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
        int i = 0;
        i = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (i == 1)
        {
            errormsg = "";
        }
        else
        {
            errormsg = "No Adventurer was created";
        }
        return i;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errormsg = ex.Message;
        return 0;
    }
    finally
    {
        dbConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: At a minimum, you've made yourself an `IF` statement, there could be an `ELSE`. Does your schema have any primary keys or unique constraints?

Comment: this sounds like a job for a `return` parameter or a `select` that provides, for example, the id of the new row if one (or nothing if not possible); note also: "verbatim string literal" - if you use `@"...your sql here..."` you can keep line breaks etc inside the string easily. You also *might* want to look at Dapper, rather than writing all the parameter code yourself

Comment: Yes I know that, The thing is that even if I have an else it will not help in my case. The problem is that when dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery() is done it will return 1 and not 0. I can also say that this is a school work and the teacher want's us to do it in a certain way.

Comment: Declare another internal variable and set it to zero, if the code enters the insert block set this variable to 1. End your query with a SELECT @variable and execute with ExecuteScalar

Comment: yes it is a sql server

Comment: Thats what exceptions are for, consider throwing an exception when the name is already there and catch where you actually use the error code variable and use the exception message instead. If you really can't use them return an enum error code which is for example `enum ErrorCode { Success = 1, NameAlreadyExists = 2, }`

Comment: Don't rely on the result of `ExecuteNonQuery`, explicitly return a result with `SELECT 1;` or `SELECT 0;` and use `ExecuteScalar` to retrieve it. Side points: you have a number of issues in your code. `dbConnection` and `dbCommand` should be in `using` blocks. Don't use `IDENT_CURRENT`, use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` as it is more reliable. `EXISTS(SELECT Ad_Fornamn FROM` the columns selected in an `EXISTS` are ignored, so you may as well do `EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the help. I have just followed what my teacher have showed us but Im gladly taking notes from people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change a lot of your current code, just, select the internal variable @Id before ending the query and execute the query with ExecuteScalar

```
String sqlstring = @
"BEGIN 
     DECLARE @Id int = 0; 
     IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Ad_Fornamn FROM [Tbl_Adventurer] WHERE Ad_Fornamn = @name) 
     BEGIN
        INSERT INTO[Tbl_Adventurer]
               (Ad_Fornamn, Ad_Efternamn, Ad_Age, Ad_Rank) 
                Values(@Ad_Fornamn, @Ad_Efternamn, @Ad_Age, @Ad_Rank)
        SELECT @Id = IDENT_CURRENT('Tbl_Adventurer')
        INSERT INTO[Tbl_Stats] 
               (Stats_Id, Strength, Dexterity, Constitution, Intelligence, Wisdom, Charisma) 
                Values(@Id, @Strength, @Dexterity, @Constitution, @Intelligence, @Wisdom, @Charisma) 
        INSERT INTO[Tbl_AdventurerKlass]
                    (Ad_Id, Kl_Id) 
                    Values(@Id, @ClassId)
    END 
SELECT @Id
END;";
```

Note the final SELECT and (to be clear) the initialization to 0 for the @Id variable. The @Id will be returned to your calling code when you use
ExecuteScalar.

```
int result = (int)dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
if (i > 0)
{
    errormsg = "";
}
else
{
    errormsg = "No Adventurer was created";
}
return result;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was going to make a function that controls if the name exist or not but this works.